# Component not updating after mapStateToProps fires

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning how to implement redux from the ground up, and have run into a problem with my components' re-rendering. My search for this issue on StackOverflow *has* produced a gazillion results, of which the answer to the question is always "you mutated your state." I have read the `connect` documentation, I've looked at a bunch of people with similar problems, and I just can't see where state mutation might be the problem here, so I'm going to try asking with my simple example.

Here's my container component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { addPokemon } from '../../../redux/actions';
import ReduxTester from '../../components/redux_tester/redux_tester';

export class ReduxTesting extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addPokemon(name, pokeType) {
        addPokemon(name, pokeType);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReduxTester
                    pokemon={this.props.pokemon}
                    addPokemon={this.addPokemon}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const MapStateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
        pokemon: state.pokemon,
    };
};

export default connect(MapStateToProps)(ReduxTesting);
```

Here's my reducer:

```
const defaultState = {
    pokemon: {},
};

export default function pokemonReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POKEMON':
            newState.pokemon[action.name] = action.pokeType;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return newState;
}
```

My specific issue is simply that ReactTesting's `componentWillReceiveProps` method is not firing, and so the component is not being updated and re-rendered. Note that the `mapStateToProps` method *is* firing after the action is dispatched. I know this is such a repetitive issue and it's unlikely that my problem is something different, but I just can't find the answer. Any assistance is appreciated.

**Edit**: For additional clarification, here is my actions.js, where I've imported the dispatch function directly:

```
import { dispatch } from './store';

// Returns an action that fits into the reducer
export function addPokemon(name, pokeType) {
    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_POKEMON',
        name,
        pokeType,
    });
}
```

**Edit 2**: I've found some additional information, but I don't understand it. It seems that in `MapStateToProps`, a re-render is triggered when I assign the entire Redux state to one prop - but not when I assign just a portion of the Redux state to prop.

This triggers a re-render:

```
const MapStateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
        pokemon: state,
    };
};
```

This does not:

```
const MapStateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
        pokemon: state.pokemon,
    };
};
```

Yet I have confirmed my redux store does have the `pokemon` property and that is where the updates are occurring in the state. Any insight?

Comment: Where is your componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: Also where is your mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: See my edit for information about my dispatch. As for your other question: I left out `componentWillReceiveProps` for brevity. As you can see, I don't actually use it in my code, but I did confirm prior with a console log statement that it isn't being called.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your action creator without going through redux won't dispatch the action:

```
 export class ReduxTesting extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }


     addPokemon(name, pokeType) {
         this.props.addPokemon(name, pokeType);
     }

    .
    .
    .


    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return({
            addPokemon: (name, pokeType) => {dispatch(addPokemon(name, pokeType))}
            })
        }

 export default connect(MapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxTesting);
```

**EDIT 2**

You're probably mutating your state, try with something like this:

Reducer

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_POKEMON':
      return {
        ...state,
        pokemon[action.name]: action.pokeType;
      };
```

Comment: Note that this can be simplified by just passing an object full of action creators to `connect`, like this:  `connect(mapState, {addPokemon})(ReduxTesting)`

Comment: @markerikson Nice, didn't know about that, I use `bindActionCreators`, but this is even better, Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I access `dispatch` in my action function through another route (probably not an ideal one), but I know it is working because my redux state updates and `mapStateToProps` is called. It's only the React component's props that aren't updating.

Comment: @Marisha can you do a `console.log(state)` inside your mapStateToProps

Comment: Yes, that is how I know the mapStateToProps is being updated. When I add a console line, I get an empty state on first render, and an updated state after I initiate the action (but not a re-render)

Comment: Okay, I've found some new information about my problem and edited the original question, if you would be willing to take a look..

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that you're mutating your state, and therefore Redux is assuming that there is no change. There is this project that detects mutation which is very helpful for me: https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant

Comment: @Anas Okay, yep. Turns out Object.assign() still references anything beyond the first set of nested properties. I didn't have any luck with the spread operator either. I did find an article that discusses why these two are insufficient for my case: http://bambielli.com/til/2017-01-29-spread-operator-deep-copy I fixed the issue by using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)) to make my copy. What a bummer that it was state mutation after all. Thank you for your help! If you edit your answer to recommend a deeper copy, I'll accept it as the answer.